# How can a Spotfire data table be sent to a web service as csv and then replace the data table with the service response?

Tags: web-services, ironpython, spotfire

I need to send my Spotfire data table to a web service as csv and then replace the data table with the service response. I assume that this can be done with IronPython behind a button. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 1):

I have addressed the similar problem but I was using different approach than the proposed IronPython script behind a button.

In my case I created a standalone C#/ASP.NET web application and I have embedded the Spotfire Web Player into the application.

I used the Spotfire JavaScript API to pick up the data marked by user within the Spotfire Web embedded part and then send it via JavaScript call to webservice on the application. The webservice did some processing and sent the data to other destination.

So my scenario was a bitt different but for yours you would also consider using the approach to embedd Spotfire Web into some app that you have full control over rather than using the IronPython script.

Answer (score 1):

This code answers the second part of your requirement but I think it also can be good starting point for the first one.

Add JSON or XML Data from a Web Service

XML example

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
import System
from System import DateTime
from System.Data import DataSet, DataTable, XmlReadMode
from System.IO import StringReader, StreamReader, StreamWriter, MemoryStream, SeekOrigin
from System.Net import HttpWebRequest
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataType, DataTableSaveSettings
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import import TextFileDataSource, TextDataReaderSettings

# get stock quotes data in XML format from Yahoo Finance API
tickerSymbol = Document.Properties["TickerSymbol"]
startDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
endDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
uri = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = %22" + tickerSymbol + "%22 and startDate = %22" + startDate + "%22 and endDate = %22" + endDate + "%22&format=xml&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys"
webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
response = webRequest.GetResponse()
streamReader = StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
xmlData = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
stringReader = StringReader(xmlData)

# read desired data fields from XML into a DataSet
dataSet = DataSet()
dataTable = DataTable("quote")
dataTable.Columns.Add("Date", System.String)
dataTable.Columns.Add("Close", System.String)
dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable)
dataSet.ReadXml(stringReader, XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema)

# build a string representing the data in tab-delimited text format
textData = "Symbol\tDate\tClose\r\n"
for row in dataTable.Rows:
 textData += tickerSymbol + "\t" + "\t".join(row.ItemArray) + "\r\n"

# make a stream from the string
stream = MemoryStream()
writer = StreamWriter(stream)
writer.Write(textData)
writer.Flush()
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

# set up the text data reader
readerSettings = TextDataReaderSettings()
readerSettings.Separator = "\t"
readerSettings.AddColumnNameRow(0)
readerSettings.SetDataType(0, DataType.String)
readerSettings.SetDataType(1, DataType.Date)
readerSettings.SetDataType(2, DataType.Currency)

# create a data source to read in the stream
textDataSource = TextFileDataSource(stream, readerSettings)

# add the data into a Data Table in Spotfire
if Document.Data.Tables.Contains("Stock Data"):
 Document.Data.Tables["Stock Data"].ReplaceData(textDataSource)
else:
 newTable = Document.Data.Tables.Add("Stock Data", textDataSource)
 tableSettings = DataTableSaveSettings (newTable, False, False)
 Document.Data.SaveSettings.DataTableSettings.Add(tableSettings)
```

JSON example

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
clr.AddReference('System.Web.Extensions')
import System
from System import DateTime
from System.Data import DataSet, DataTable
from System.IO import StreamReader, StreamWriter, MemoryStream, SeekOrigin
from System.Net import HttpWebRequest
from System.Web.Script.Serialization import JavaScriptSerializer
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataType, DataTableSaveSettings
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import import TextFileDataSource, TextDataReaderSettings

# get stock quotes data in JSON format from Yahoo Finance API
tickerSymbol = Document.Properties["TickerSymbol"]
startDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
endDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
uri = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = %22" + tickerSymbol + "%22 and startDate = %22" + startDate + "%22 and endDate = %22" + endDate + "%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys"
webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
response = webRequest.GetResponse()
streamReader = StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
jsonData = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
js = JavaScriptSerializer()
dataDict = js.Deserialize(jsonData,object)

# build a string representing the data in tab-delimited text format
textData = "Symbol\tDate\tClose\r\n" 
for quote in dataDict["query"]["results"]["quote"]:
     textData += tickerSymbol + "\t" + quote["Date"] + "\t" + quote["Close"] + "\r\n"

# make a stream from the string
stream = MemoryStream()
writer = StreamWriter(stream)
writer.Write(textData)
writer.Flush()
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

# set up the text data reader
readerSettings = TextDataReaderSettings()
readerSettings.Separator = "\t"
readerSettings.AddColumnNameRow(0)
readerSettings.SetDataType(0, DataType.String)
readerSettings.SetDataType(1, DataType.Date)
readerSettings.SetDataType(2, DataType.Currency)

# create a data source to read in the stream
textDataSource = TextFileDataSource(stream, readerSettings)

# add the data into a Data Table in Spotfire
if Document.Data.Tables.Contains("Stock Data"):
     Document.Data.Tables["Stock Data"].ReplaceData(textDataSource)
else:
     newTable = Document.Data.Tables.Add("Stock Data", textDataSource)
     tableSettings = DataTableSaveSettings (newTable, False, False)
     Document.Data.SaveSettings.DataTableSettings.Add(tableSettings)
```

Source: 
http://spotfired.blogspot.com/search?q=web+service
http://spotfire.tibco.com/tips/2014/03/03/streaming-xml-and-json-data-from-the-web-directly-into-spotfire-clients-using-script-controls/